How can I get this character's body parts to align with the intended animation?
I have a model with some body parts/bones that aren't behaving correctly.  This character has several scorpion legs that should be folded up against his back when he's in robot mode.  The legs on the left side are behaving correctly, but the corresponding right-side parts have incorrect position/rotation/scaling, as shown:

One can also see that this problem persists through the included animation to its end, when the character has transformed into another mode:

This is affecting the mesh and the armature.  Here you can see that the corresponding bones are also misbehaving:

When I select the armature and go into Rest Position, the problem geometry snaps into place, but you can see that the bones are not at all symmetrical:

I should also add that other parts of the mesh are working correctly.  The robot's arms and regular legs seem to have no problem following the animation and maintaining symmetry.
I could sure use some help.  I can't seem to figure out why the left side is behaving correctly but the right side isn't.  I'm having similar problems with a handful of other characters, so figuring this out would be a huge help. How can I correct the mesh and armature to behave correctly?
Here's my .blend file:  my blend file
Here's the .FBX I'm importing: my fbx

Importing ASCII fbx files is not supported in Blender.

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
Analysis
One part of the problem is that the bones hierarchy is not the same from the "scapula" to the "fingers" comparing left and right sides. There are extra bones labeled "transform*" on the right side. The other issue on the right side is that some bones rotation and scale are suspicious (see selected blue bones in next figure). Consequently there are more modifications to do than "just" skip the "transform*" bones in the parent-children chain...

These issues are present also in the provided .FBX file.
Here is the left scapula definition:
    Model: 1844443556544, "Model::bn_l_dummy_scapula01", "LimbNode" {
        Version: 232
        Properties70:  {
            P: "ScalingMax", "Vector3D", "Vector", "",0,0,0
            P: "PreferedAngleX", "double", "Number", "",28.3604640960693
            P: "PreferedAngleY", "double", "Number", "",88.2721481323242
            P: "PreferedAngleZ", "double", "Number", "",29.1923065185547
            P: "DefaultAttributeIndex", "int", "Integer", "",0
            P: "Lcl Translation", "Lcl Translation", "", "A+",0.258540213108063,0.157943025231361,-0.209541767835617
            P: "Lcl Rotation", "Lcl Rotation", "", "A+",28.3604640960693,88.2721481323242,29.1923065185547
        }
        Shading: Y
        Culling: "CullingOff"
    }

to compare to the right scapula definition:
    Model: 1843926802096, "Model::bn_r_dummy_scapula01", "LimbNode" {
        Version: 232
        Properties70:  {
            P: "ScalingMax", "Vector3D", "Vector", "",0,0,0
            P: "PreferedAngleX", "double", "Number", "",-1.06170423201744e-13
            P: "PreferedAngleY", "double", "Number", "",90
            P: "DefaultAttributeIndex", "int", "Integer", "",0
            P: "Lcl Translation", "Lcl Translation", "", "A+",0.258540004491806,1.308070063591,-0.17561000585556
            P: "Lcl Rotation", "Lcl Rotation", "", "A+",-1.06170423201744e-13,90,0
        }
        Shading: Y
        Culling: "CullingOff"
    }

Right rotation is suspicious at (0°,90°,0°) and without "PreferedAngleZ" record.
Here is the parenting:
    ;Model::bn_l_dummy_scapula01, Model::bn_chest01
    C: "OO",1844443556544,1843915638592

    ;Model::bn_r_dummy_scapula01, Model::transform1
    C: "OO",1843926802096,1843926810096

    ;Model::transform1, Model::bn_chest01
    C: "OO",1843926810096,1843915638592

"transform1" is between "bn_r_dummy_scapula01" and "bn_chest01", as shown in the Outliner.

Man, that's some good intel.  Thank you!  Do you have any suggestions on how I could fix the problem?

I have no idea about how to make things right at the export to FBX. But it would be the obvious thing to do instead of curing the rig in Blender afterwards. About Blender, I try to fix some bones but at the price of loosing the animation. Is is OK for you ?

Thanks for all the help, but I'm determined to figure this all out and keep the animation intact.

I do believe this is the root of my problem.  I tried re-parenting the bones to their correct parents and deleting the transform bones, but it had no effect.  Is there any way to negate the transform bones' influence on the armature/animation?
